# Combining Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

im trying to figure out how to combine two Standard deviations of two data sets.

Iam calculating the mass. I have density and volume data each with there own SD.

So Mass = Volume X density

Example M = 1000 ± 10 * 1500 ± 25 
=1500000± ??

Comment: This looks like a combined measurement uncertainty of a product which you'll find at e.g. http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Uncertainty/combination.html Taking your ± values as standard errors this leads to 
M=1000±10*1500±25=1500000. Then  
(u(M)/M)^2=(u(V)/V)^2+(u(d)/d)^2 =0.0001+0.000277778 =0.000377778 so u(M)/M=0.019436506 and 
u(M)=29154.75947.
So your answer is 1500000± 29155

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}   \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$
Assuming volume $V$ and density $d$ are measured independently,  you can find the standard error of the volume by using the iterated expextation theorem:
$$
   \E X  = \E \E X|Y  
$$
and its cousine, the iterated variance theorem:
$$
   \Var X = \Var \E X|Y  + \E \Var X|Y
$$
Apply this to $M = V * d$ to get: (asssuming independence of $V$ and $d$)
$$
   \Var M = \Var V\cdot d = \Var \E Vd | d  + \E \Var Vd | d \\
   =  \Var_d V\cdot d +\E_d d^2 \Var V = (\E V)^2 \Var d + \E(d^2) \Var V
$$
and using $\E(d^2) = \Var d + (\E d)^2$.

Comment: Is there not a simpler way of doing this. Along the lines of sqroot of 10 * 25

Comment: @Craig As I suggested in my comment on the question (maybe not very clearly!) 1500000 * sqroot((10/1000)^2 + (25/1500)^2)